# Drupal - Keep getting logged out on front page only

Tags: drupal, authentication

Drupal 7.19
Acquia hosting
using Yottaa for optimization and monitoring

Problem: when trying to log in from home, we're experiencing something odd: we keep getting "logged out" ONLY on the front page. When you click anywhere inside the site, we get the admin toolbar and contextual links back.  But we can't update the front page at all because it acts like it's logged out only for the front page.

This only happens when we're at home working on the site.  This does not happen when we're in the work office.

Anyone experienced this? Don't know at what level is this occurring in...drupal, yottaa?

Answer (score 1):

Found out the issue.  It was a specific caching for the homepage on Yottaa's CDN.  Once I turned this off, I was able to edit the home page again.

Note: They said that turning it off is not recommended. Instead, they recommend to flush the cache.  Either way, found out what was causing the issue.